# How do you change a linq group IQueryable<IEnumerable<T>> to IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-group

How do you change a linq group `IQueryable<IEnumerable<T>>` to `IQueryable<T>` ?
So that i can join the iqueryable with other entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548748(v=vs.100).aspx) method is for:

```
yourQueryable.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

MyIQueryable.SelectMany(item => item).AsQueryable()